# Send javascript object with data and file to asp.net core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I need send data with file in a `javascript` object to `asp.net core` but 
when it arrives at the asp.net core method, arrives with null values (`List<Upload> listUpload`)

I did a test removing the File property from the javascript object and it does not appear anymore null, the problem is with the File property that it can not map with the model property called File of type IFormFile.

`javascript` code:

```
jQuery('#tblDocuments > tbody > tr').each(function () {
   checkBox = jQuery(this).find('td').eq(0).children();

   inputFile = jQuery(this).find('td').eq(2).children()[0].files[0]; 

    let Upload = {
        File: inputFile,
        CodigoVendaArquivo: res,
        CodigoClienteArquivo: cliente,
        Checkbox: checkBox[0].id
    };
    listUpload.push(Upload);
});
```

I'm trying to send with `fetch`:

```
fetch('../../upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(listUpload)
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {

    if (res == 1) {
     // success
    }

});
```

Here's my `asp.net core` method:

```
[Route("upload")]
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload([FromBody] List<Upload> listUpload)
{
    // something
}
```

Here's my Model:

```
public class Upload
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public string CodigoVendaArquivo { get; set; }
    public string CodigoClienteArquivo { get; set; }
    public string Checkbox { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Remove the file from the POST request and access your file in the controller as (foreach var file in Request.Files)

Comment: Remove from the POST? but i need send in POST the javascript object... you mean in the controller parameter?

Comment: remove the file property and use JavaScript FormData, the access file in controller as at my first comment

Comment: Look at this https://cmatskas.com/upload-files-to-the-server-using-javascript-and-mvc-webapi/

Comment: I've use formData before but i need the file and other data in one model.. and are multiple files, thats why the list

Answer (score 1):

Avoid embedding an `IFormFile` within the `Upload` class. When uploading something like **`IList<Upload>`** where its list item **has a property of `IFormFile`**, you might encounter **an bug** that results in a crazy memory leak (It ate me about 6.7G memory until I address it). For more information, see

- [ASP.NET Core #4802](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4802)
- [ASP.NET MVC #8782](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8782)

The easiest way to walk around it, as [WahidBitar comments on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4802#issuecomment-456117442), is to create a wrapper to receive the payload.

---

As for your question itself, you should avoid embedding an `IFormFile` within the `Upload` class.

Here's a working sample :

```
public class UploadPayload{
    public IList<Upload> Uploads{get;set;}

    public class IFormFileWrapper {
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    }
    public class Upload
    {
        // See https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8782
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
        public IFormFileWrapper CodigoFile { get; set; }
        public string CodigoVendaArquivo { get; set; }
        public string CodigoClienteArquivo { get; set; }
        public string Checkbox { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And also change your action method as below:

```
public JsonResult Upload([FromBody] List listUpload)
public IActionResult Upload(UploadPayload listUpload)
{ 
    ... 
}
```

**Client Side :**

To construct a `formData`, create a `getFormData()` function :

```
    function getFormData(listUpload){
        var formData = new FormData();
        function getFieldName(index,name){
            return "Uploads[" + index + "]." + name ;
        };
        function getFileName(index,name){
            return "Uploads[" + index + "].CodigoFile." + name ;
        };

        for(var i =0 ;i <listUpload.length; i++){
            var upload = listUpload[i];
            formData.append(getFieldName(i, 'CodigoVendaArquivo'), upload.CodigoVendaArquivo);
            formData.append(getFieldName(i, 'CodigoClienteArquivo'), upload.CodigoClienteArquivo);
            formData.append(getFieldName(i, 'Checkbox'),upload.Checkbox)
            formData.append(getFileName(i, 'File'), upload.File);
        }
        return formData;
    }
```

Now we could send the formData in the following way:

```
    jQuery('#tblDocuments > tbody > tr').each(function () {
        ...
        listUpload.push(Upload);
    }

    var formData = getFormData(listUpload);
    fetch('../../upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(listUpload),
        body:formData,
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        if (res == 1) {
            // success
        }
    });
```